# alignment issue in td

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have use the following code snippet to align the multiple div with in the td

```
<style type="text/css">
        td {
            border-collapse: collapse;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  display: table-cell;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*padding: 0.7em;*/
  height: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box!important;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important;
        }
        .e-gridtreeexpand {
    width: 0;
       height: 0;
       border-bottom: 10px solid black;
       border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}
.e-gridtreecollapse {
    width: 0;
       height: 0;
       border-top: 5px solid transparent;
       border-left: 10px solid black;
       border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}    </style>
   <div style="height:30px;width:200px;">
       <table>
           <tr>
               <td><div><div class="intend" style="height:1px; float:left; width:0px;"></div><div class="e-gridtreeexpand" style="float: left"></div><form style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="ejGridTreeGridEditForm"><input style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" name="taskId" id="ejGridTreeGridtaskId" value="1" class="e-field e-ejinputtext"></form></div></td>
           </tr>
       </table>
   </div>
```

How to align this div horizontally with in the td

Comment: Please post your full code to JSFiddle so we can see what's going on.

Comment: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7qWB5/

Answer (score 1):

Please check [JSFiddle url](http://jsfiddle.net/7qWB5/1/) ,

```
<div style='float:right'><form style="height: 100%;"></form></div>
```